# From java.util.concurrent.Future<T> to play.libs.F.Promise<T>: How to do that in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, akka

I am using play framework to implement a REST API service.

In one function I am using a java async library to talk to another service and it returns a
`java.util.concurrent.Future<T>` that I map (using Guava `Futures.transform(~)`) into a `java.util.concurrent.Future<play.mvc.Result>`.

Now, how do I make it a `play.libs.F.Promise<Result>` so that I can make an `AsyncResult`?

I found `play.libs.Akka.asPromise(scala.concurrent.Future<T> future)` but I cannot find a way (in Java) to get a scala future from a java one.

**EDIT TEMPORARY SOLUTION**:
Here is what I am using right now:

```
Future<T> future = asyncGetTheFuture();
Promise<T> promise = Akka.future(new JFutureToPromise<T>(tempFuture));
```

with

```
    class JFutureToPromise<T> implements Callable<T> {
        final Future<T> future;
        final long time;
        final TimeUnit unit;

        private JFutureToPromise(Future<T> future, long time, TimeUnit unit) {
            this.future = future;
            this.time = time;
            this.unit = unit;
        }

        private JFutureToPromise(Future<T> future) {
            this(future, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        @Override
        public T call() throws Exception {
            return future.get(time, unit);  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to non-blockingly/non-pollingly transform an arbitrary j.u.c.Future into an async Future/Promise.
Try it and see for yourself :)

Comment: I have tried, it's just that Promise is extending j.u.c.Future ... so I had hope.

Comment: That direction is very simple; Promise/Future is strictly more powerful/flexible than j.u.c.Future

Comment: If only Java's Future supported the concept if a completion listener (observer) then you be able to create a bridge between Java's Future and Scala's Future via a Promise but alas such things do not exist...

Comment: Fortunately my dear friend Doug might be of assistance there in the future (excuse my pun): http://download.java.net/lambda/b103/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: Wow! Now that's what I'm talking about :)

Comment: @cmbaxter I have a scenario where a java api provides a callback, but I can't figure out how to convert to a promise. I posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582411/how-to-convert-callback-to-a-promise. Can you help out?