# How to Convert callback to a Promise

Tags: java, callback, playframework-2.0, promise

I am using play framework and Apache Kafka.

I have a POST method which sends a message to Kafka. Kafka has an API method

[public java.util.concurrent.Future send(ProducerRecord record,
                                                        Callback callback)](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send%28org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord,%20org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback%29)

of which the Javadoc says

> Asynchronously send a record to a topic and invoke the provided
>   callback when the send has been acknowledged.

I am exposing this functionality using the play framework. I want to return a `Promise<Result>` from the Controller method but can't figure out how to implement this in a non-blocking way. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching found the answer with some help from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956704/java-scala-future-driven-by-a-callback).

Following is the code

```
RedeemablePromise<Result> promise = RedeemablePromise.empty();

kafkaProducer.send(record, (metadata, ex) -> {
    if (ex != null) {
        promise.failure(ex);
    } else {
        promise.success(created(Json.toJson(new ProduceResult())));
    }
});
```